# How to get monthly report in Pivot format in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to get monthly report in Pivot format in SQL?

I am trying to generate a pivot format of monthly report in ..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `conditional aggregation`

```
select SourceID,   
       sum(case when month(FileReceivedDate)= 1 then 1 else 0 end ) as Jan,
       sum(case when month(FileReceivedDate)= 2 then 1 else 0 end ) as Feb,
       sum(case when month(FileReceivedDate)= 3 then 1 else 0 end ) as Mar,
       sum(case when month(FileReceivedDate)= 4 then 1 else 0 end ) as Apr
   from tab
  group by SourceId
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. but what if Jan is on 2 different years.. ?

Comment: @goofyui you're welcome, in that case you need to add `year()` function for each occurence such as `sum(case when month(FileReceivedDate)= 1 and year(FileReceivedDate)= 2019 then 1 else 0 end ) as Jan 2019` and `sum(case when month(FileReceivedDate)= 1 and year(FileReceivedDate)= 2018 then 1 else 0 end ) as Jan 2018` .. etc.